# Azure File Storage on Windows 7

Tags: smb, azure, mapped-drive

I have a folder share in Azure file storage that was working beautifully.  I have connected several Windows 10 computers using the net use command and it is working without a problem.  I had a user who is running Windows 7 contact me stating they could not get connected to the folder share, it kept giving them "Access Denied".
Is mapping a folder share as a network drive only a function of SMB 3.0 or is there a way to get Windows 7 computers connected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, your Windows 7 is on-premises PC client. An on-premises client application only supports SMB 3.0. However, Windows 7 only supports SMB 2.1. On-premise Windows 7 could not mount Azure File Shares.  More information please refer to the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share)

Comment: Your interpretation of my description is correct.  That's unfortunate news, however that is what I figured the problem was.  Need to upgrade Windows 10!